# C# Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument Disrupt the PDF Size

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a problem with Spire.Pdf. I have an API code and when i send a request to the service, API returns a PDF path. I got the PDF path and store a variable. After that, i create a WebClient and download file from the server.

```
var i = 0;
string ak = item.pdf + "";
string dos = LoginForm.appDataDizini + "/" + stuff.takip2 + "_" + i + ".pdf";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(ak, @"" + dos);
```

**The problem starts after this step.** I read file from the temporary folder with PdfDocument class and i send to printer (in this scenario printer is set to Microsoft Print to PDF).

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"" + dos);
doc.PrintSettings.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
doc.PrintSettings.PrinterName = Properties.Settings.Default.yazici_1;//Microsoft Print to PDF
doc.Print();
```

The resulting PDF file is in A4 size and distortions occur. For example;

[image: This is Unwanted Output]

[image: This is Wanted Output]

Photo 1 is created by second code block. Photo 2 is created by first code block.

Photo 1 size is A4 and the other photo size is A6.
When i print the pdf size is changing.

**I tried to** change printer size settings to A6, it isn't work properly. It compressed the A4 output. The problem persists when I print the file. This problem corrupts the barcode on the middle. What should i do?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to write Spire version. I am using Spire free edition. I talked with Spire customer service and they said that there is a bug in free edition. There is no hotfix right now, maybe next days they will publish new version. If you are facing this problem, you can use PdfiumViewer.2.10.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code before invoking doc.Print():

```
doc.PrintSettings.SelectSinglePageLayout(Spire.Pdf.Print.PdfSinglePageScalingMode.FitSize, true);
```